# How can I access multiple user spaces from adb?

Tags: adb, usb-connection-mode, multi-user

I am running KitKat on a tablet with two users: primary (owner) and secondary. I need to access a file generated by an app of the secondary user.

When I plug the tablet into my (Ubuntu) desktop via USB, it mounts as a media device (MTP), and shows me the base folder for the currently active user. [1] But the file I want is elsewhere on the system, so I connected from the command line via `adb shell` instead.

Connecting via ADB gives me access to deeper folders (`/mnt` `/proc` etc) but I couldn't find the file where I expected it [2], so I looked in `/sdcard` anyway. To my surprise I recognised the contents as the base folder of the owner account, even though the currently active user is the secondary user.

This also tells me that, if I ever need to, I won't be able to access the base folder for the secondary user via `adb shell`.

How can I access the tablet from `adb shell` as the secondary user, rather than the primary (owner) user? (Being able to access the secondary user's files is good enough.)

[1] I'm not sure what the proper term here is. I mean the folder with Android, Download and Pictures, specific to a particular user.

[2] FWIW I am exporting an OPML file from [Flym](https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdid=net.fred.feedex). Flym reports that the OPML export is generated at `/storage/emulated/10/Flym_123456789.opml` but I can only get as far as `/storage/emulated` - there is no subfolder called `10`, only `legacy` which is the same as `/sdcard` (the primary/owner's base folder, not the secondary user's base folder).

Comment: For those who ends up at this post with same or similar issue, see [How can I access the emulated sdcard for another user on a rooted nexus 10](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/73377)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `legacy/` locations are always pointing to the data of the currently active user. Let me first point to a few related questions/answers explicitly dealing with those multi-user storage issues for some background:

- [Why did /sdcard/ turn into /sdcard/0/ with 4.2?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/35543/16575)
- [Confusing internal memory folder structure](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/85696/16575)

So to find the files of the secondary user:

- list the sub-directories of `/data/media` and `/storage/emulated`
- restrict your search to sub-directories whose names are simply "numbers"
- the `0` candidates belong to the owner, higher numbers are of secondary users
- external storage is something different: `/sdcard/0` points to the internal sdcard, while `/sdcard/1` should be the external (if available). Similarly for storage attached via OTG

Remember you might need to be root to access data of a user other than the one currently active on the device.

Also see:

- [Android Folder Hierarchy](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/46926/16575)
- our tag-wikis for [file-system](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/file-system/info) and [files](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/files/info)

Comment: this helps me understand what I should see, but what I actually see is just /storage/emulated/legacy (no numeric folders) and I don't have access to /data/media (permission denied) - I'm going to try restarting and never logging in as owner

Comment: As I wrote: "you might need to be root" (which explains the "permission denied"). Is your device rooted?

Comment: it isn't (a bit scared to, seems like there is no reliable process?)

Comment: but I can confirm this: reboot device, don't log in as owner, log in as secondary, hook up usb, access via MTP: can see secondary user folder, access via adb shell: can see /storage/emulated/legacy as owner user (not secondary user) - no other folders appear under /storage/emulated

Comment: When logged in with the secondary user, `emulated/` should point to the secondary user's data. No way to access all without root. And correct, there's no *official* process to root your device; you might want to check our [rooting tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/rooting/info) and [rooting index](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/1184/16575) to check for generals and for your device. If not listed, be welcome to ask a new question for this.

Comment: thanks re rooting :) just to check I'm not being dumb: when I `adb shell` I am not picking a user (like when you `ssh user@host`) - I did try running `am pick-user 10` once on the shell, but that had no noticeable effect - but it sounds like rooting solves all problems :)

Comment: When you `adb shell`, you're the user `shell`. Almost all users on Android correspond to some app, root being an exception – so you can think of it as being in the realms of the "shell" app. Switching to a different user might be restricted to root again (I have to admit I never tried, so I cannot be sure about that). But yes, having root makes many things a lot easier :)

Answer (score 1):

In Android 13 I finally found the folder at
`/data/media/USERID`